# iPad UIPopoverController How to Set the Title

Tags: ipad, xamarin.ios, uipopovercontroller

I have a UIPopoverController which displays a table. I use the PresentFromBarButtonItem method.

How can I give the pop up a title to display, much list the UISpliter does?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

#### 1. Set title parameter of your `UITableViewController`;

#### 2. Add your `UITableViewController` to an `UINavigationController`.

```
@interface YourTableViewController : UITableViewController < ... >
...
@end
```

...

...

```
YourTableViewController *vc = [[YourTableViewController alloc] init...  ;
vc.title = @"Some Title";

// add vc to an UINavigationController then forget it.
UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc]
                                initWithRootViewController:vc];
[vc release];

UIPopoverController *some_pvc = [[UIPopoverController alloc]
                                  initWithContentViewController:nav];
[nav release];
```

Then show the `UIPopoverController some_pvc` by sending `presentPopoverFromRect: ...` message to an `UIViewController` you will see the title bar

[image]

Comment: apple programming is pretty simple as usual

Comment: Do you know what's up with the weird spacing in this scenario? Like, why is the right nav button always jammed up to the upper right corner, and the title close to the top? And I don't seem to have any way to get the title bar to blend with the popover style itself.

Comment: I found this useful for the iPhone as well.. only problem is that my Nav bar doesn't actually get drawn within the popover so a ghost title image appears instead.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what you mean by UISpliter, but you need to "wrap" your view controller in a UINavigationController and show the navigation controller in a popover. Your view controller's title property will appear above the view controller's view.